# Google Drive API - Change ID of the file

Tags: api, rest, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Is it possible to change the ID of a file created via Google Drive API v2 **without** copying and deleting the original file?

Comment: It might be helpful if you could tell why do you need to change the id and where you'll get new value

Comment: Sure. I keep the permission level of documents on "Anyone who has the link" and share it to X amount of users, who do not have Google accounts at all. I would like to able to "revoke" the access to some users by changing the documents ID, as IDs are pretty unguessable.

Comment: The new value I would like to get in the response of the API request or somehow else if possible after the API transaction.

Comment: I think it is not possible, since it is auto generated by the Drive itself. The Alternative way is like the idea that you said(you have no choice but to use this) is to create another file(copy of the original file) then provide the access only to your designated target. Check this [Google Drive Rest API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk) to know more about it.